# How to export(writeRaster) single raster from multi-band stack/brick/spatraster one by one using R?

Tags: raster, r, terra

```
library(terra)

a=rast(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=1:100)

b=rast(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=1:100)

c=rast(nrows=10,ncols=10,vals=1:100)

test <- c(a,b,c)

for (i in 1:3) 
{
  r=test[[i]]
  writeRaster(r,paste0("E:/test",i,'.tif'))
}
```

This is my way to do it. I want to know is there a easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a vector of filenames to `writeRaster` directly to extract multiple layers:

```
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.7

a <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, vals=1:100)

b <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, vals=1:100)

c <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, vals=1:100)

test <- c(a,b,c)

fnames <- paste0("test", 1:nlyr(test), ".tif")

writeRaster(test, fnames)
```